# have the id of the item chosen for a POST request reactjs

Tags: reactjs, post

Hi I have a problem: I want to get the id of the employee item to send it to the backend to make my sql query.

Here is my react code:

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({
        etude: "",
        group: "",
        date: "",
        toDoId: 0,
        employeeId: ""
    });

const configFetchValidateTask = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify(values)
};

const validateTask = () => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/validate-task`, configFetchValidateTask)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(res => res)
};
```

and I this in my react component return

```
<select>
  {employees.map(employee => 
    <option onChange={() => getEmployeeId(employee.employee_id)}>{employee.employee_name_tname</option>)}
</select>
```

I don't have the variable used in the values object

except that I have this error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just Changes this
`onChange={getEmployeeId(employee.employee_id)}`
to `onChange={() => getEmployeeId(employee.employee_id)}`.
And you'll see it prevent the unnecessary re-rendering.

Comment: I don't have the previous error anymore but I have another one here: uncaught (in promise) syntaxeError: Unexpected token 0 in JSON at position 0